# How to pass list values from an Action method to another in the same controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

How to pass data from a method to another inside a controller and display.
The first method have list of values and this has to pass to the another and display that data from the view
 first action method:

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult  matchpin(string id)
    {
        int d = Convert.ToInt32(id);
        List<pin> plist = new List<pin>();
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("getpin", con))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pin", d);
                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    var pin = new pin()
                    {
                        // Vid=Convert.ToInt32(reader["Vid"]),

                        po = Convert.ToString(reader["po"]),

                    };
                    plist.Add(pin);
                }


            }
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index","home",new{ s =plist});

    }
```

second action method:

```
 public ActionResult Index(List<pin> plist)
        {

           // return View();
            ViewBag.s = plist;
            return View("Index");
            //return new ContentResult { Content =TempData["Data"].ToString() };

        }
```

Comment: please add your attempted code example

Comment: @ Ahmed Yousif done sir

Comment: please try to  return RedirectToAction("Index","home",new{ plist}) instead of  return RedirectToAction("Index","home",new{ s =plist}) and try again

Comment: @ Ahmed Yousif i tried but it returns null

Comment: try to debug it because I tried it after change it is working fine

Answer (score 0):

redirect in the first action method has to be

```
return RedirectToAction("Index","home",new{plist});
```

instead of

```
return RedirectToAction("Index","home",new{s=plist});
```

because ASP MVC framework match it by method parameter name so you have to pass it with the same name in the action method two which is `plist`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use TempData: first store your value in TempData, and then redirectToAction:

```
TempData.MyList=plist;
return RedirectToAction("Index","home");
```

Comment: thank you.I have retrieved data usind TempData and stored it to a viewbag ,but in view i couldnt display the value(even it contains values)

Comment: <select name="postoffice"  >
                                            <option>-select-</option>
                                     @if (ViewBag.s != null)
                                          {
                                        foreach (var f in ViewBag.s)
                                   {
                                            <option value="@f.po">@f.po</option>
                                        
                                         }
                            } 
       
                                         </select>

Comment: the above is what i tried to display while debugging it shows the values but not displaying in the browser .Why?

Answer (score 0):

Using action you can pass limited data.
Mvc provides tempdata to pass data from one action to another.

You can also using session for storing data.

e. g
For passing data:
TempData["mydata"] =myList;

For data retrieval :
var data=TempData["mydata"] ;

Hope that clarify you question.

Comment: can i put these Tempdata items into viewbag?like ViewBag.s=TempData["mydata"]?

Comment: Yes you can assign to viewbag

Comment: <select name="postoffice" > <option>-select-</option> @if (ViewBag.s != null) { foreach (var f in ViewBag.s) { <option value="@f.po">@f.po</option> } } </select>

Comment: the above is what i tried to display while debugging it shows the values but not displaying in the browser .Why?

Comment: You need to convert viewbag. S to dictionary then iterate

Answer (score 0):

Using action you can pass limited data.
Mvc provides **TempData** to pass data from one action to another.

You can also using session for storing data.

e.g

For storing data:
TempData["mydata"]=data;

For retrieving :

var storedData=TempData["mydata"]